# Displaying the Radio Button Value in javascript after Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, drop-down-menu, radio-button

i have make an Ajax request and it succeeded in JSON format and i wanted it to display in a table and have radio button in front of each table so that it will display the shipping fee at the bottom of the table but the problem is the table is displaying the table but not displaying the shipping fee value at the bottom of the table?

```
$.ajax(ajaxurl,{
      type: 'GET',
      data: { action: 'getImageProduct',value: kukui,value2: barang,},   
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
            var txtHint = document.getElementById('txtHint');
            var meja = '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Radio</th><th>Shipping Name</th><th>Shipping Fee</th><th>Shipping Time</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

            $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='choose']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                $('#radioresult').val($("[type='radio']:checked").val());

              }
            });

            $.each(data.msg, function(index, value){
                //console.log(index);
                meja += '<tr>';
                meja += '<td><input type="radio" name="choose" value="'+value.shipping_fee+'"></td>';
                meja += '<td>'+value.shipping_name+'</td>';
                meja += '<td>'+value.shipping_fee+'</td>';
                meja += '<td>'+value.shipping_time+'</td>';
                meja += '</tr>';
            });
            meja += '</tbody></table>';
            txtHint.innerHTML = meja;
            //$("#txtHint").append(event_data);
        },
```

The radio value display nothing at the bottom of the table

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the `input` selector within the radio `click` event.
And also [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for form elements. If you're trying to set the text of the `<div>`, use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

Change this :

```
$('#radioresult').val($("[type='radio']:checked").val());
```

To this :

```
$('#radioresult').text($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()); // added input selector
```

Or this would do it too :

```
$('#radioresult').text(radioValue); // use radioValue instead
```

Comment: Could you `console.log(radioValue);` inside the `if(radioValue){` block and see what is the result of it?

Comment: Also, could you show the `#radioresult` html element?

Comment: There's nothing happen if i ```console.log(radioValue);```

Comment: im using this html code to display the shipping price value ```<div id="radioresult">test</div>```

Comment: What is the output if you do that after this line : `var radioValue = $("input[name='choose']:checked").val();` ?

Comment: So there are no error or any log on console when you click the radio button?

Comment: I'm sorry to catch it for so long, so actually you are setting a `<div>`, not a form element, I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes, i need to display the radio value at ```<div id="radioresult">test</div>```

Comment: Did you try the updated answer and still not showing?

Comment: yes, still not showng. im using jquery ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>```

Comment: do i need to add onclick function?